# How does end-of-year interact with mutual fund prices (if it does)?

Tags: mutual-funds, dividends

Should I expect prices of mutual fund shares to go up in anticipation of dividends, down after dividends have paid out ... or just trust that the market has already reacted to that and the price is basically fair throughout the period?

(I've generally been paranoid and tended not to play with my funds around this time of year, but that may be pure superstition.)

Clarifications: USA, open-ended index funds are my immediate interest, but the answers would be most general if we could cover some of the other varieties (and, if folks are so inclined, locations).

Comment: Are you talking about open-end funds, closed-end funds or exchange-traded funds? Each would be different to my mind.

Comment: What country are you talking about? In some countries, like the US, funds often distribute capital gains towards the end of the year, which may affect your decision to buy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is applicable to the US.  Similar rules may hold in some
other countries as well.

The shares in an open-ended (non-exchange-traded) mutual fund are not
traded on stock exchanges and the "market" does not determine the share
price the way it does for shares in companies as brokers make offers to
buy and sell stock shares. The price of one share of 
the mutual fund (usually called Net Asset Value (NAV) per share) is usually calculated at the close of business, and is, as the name implies, the net
worth of all the shares in companies that the fund owns plus cash on hand
etc divided by the number of mutual fund shares outstanding.

The NAV per share of a mutual fund might or might not increase in anticipation
of the distribution to occur, but the NAV per share very definitely falls on 
the day that the distribution *is* declared. If you choose to re-invest
your distribution in the same fund, then you will own *more* shares
at a lower NAV per share but the *total value of your investment will not
change at all.*  If you had 100 shares currently priced at $10 and 
the fund declares a distribution of $2 per share, you will 
be reinvesting $200 to buy more shares but the fund will be
selling you additional shares at $8 per share (and of course, the
100 shares you hold will be priced at $8 per share too.  So, you
will have

100 previous shares worth only $800 now + 25 new shares worth $200
for a total of 125 shares at $8 = $1000 total investment, just as before.

If you take the distribution in cash, then you still hold the 100
shares but they are worth only $800 now, and the fund will send you
the $200 as cash. Either way, there is no change in your net worth.

*However*, (assuming that the fund is is not in a tax-advantaged account),
that $200 is taxable income to you regardless of whether you reinvest
it or take it as cash. The fund will tell you what part of that $200
is dividend income (as well as what part is Qualified Dividend income), 
what part is short-term capital gains, and what part is long-term capital
gains; you declare the income in the appropriate categories on your
tax return, and are taxed accordingly.

So, what advantage is there in re-investing?
Well, your *basis* in those shares has increased and so if and when
you sell the shares, you will owe less tax. If you had bought the
original 100 shares at $10 and sell the 125
shares a few years later at $11 and collect $1375, you owe (long-term
capital gains) tax on 
just $1375-$1200
=$175  (which can also be calculated as $1 gain on each of the original
100 shares = $100 plus $3 gain on the 25 new shares = $175).
In the past, some people would forget the intermediate transactions and think
that they had invested $1000 initially and gotten $1375 back for
a gain of $375 and pay taxes on $375 instead. This is less likely
to occur now since mutual funds are now required to
report more information on the sale
to the shareseller than they used to in the past.

So, should you *buy* shares in a mutual fund right now? Most mutual
fund companies publish preliminary estimates in November and December
of what distributions each fund will be making by the end of the
year. They also usually
advise against purchasing new shares during this period because
one ends up "buying a dividend".  If, for example, you bought those
100 shares at $10 on the Friday after Thanksgiving and the fund distributes
that $2 per share  on December 15, you still have $1000 on
December 15, but now owe taxes on $200 that you would not have
had to pay if you had postponed buying those shares till after the
distribution was paid.

Nitpickers: for simplicity of exposition, I have not gone into the
detailed chronology of
when the fund goes ex-dividend, when the distribution is recorded, 
and when cash is paid out, etc., but merely treated all these events
as happening simultaneously.

Comment: Dividend is not a problem, and more than that - many funds actually accrue dividends, so buying the day before dividend won't help you much. In any case - dividends is something you actually get in hand. The more costly issue is capital gains distribution - you don't get any money, but you end up owing taxes for your portion of the fund's capital gains. That is why it is not advisable to buy in during the last couple of months: you're not buying dividends - you're buying capital gains.

Comment: @littleadv I thought that if a _mutual fund did not distribute dividends earned from the stocks they held (as well as the net capital gains from the stocks they sold during the year to the fund's shareholders)_, then the fund had to pay income taxes on the non-distributed amounts? Some mutual funds distribute dividends and capital gains in March and December, and since I choose to receive these as cash (and not re-invest them), I do receive the capital gains distributions as cash, not just the dividends part as cash.

Comment: No, in the US funds don't pay taxes. They have capital gains due to selling of stocks to rebalance, or to pay cashing out investors, and it is reported to the fund holders at the end of the year based on their rate of holdings.

Comment: @littleadv I just don't understand the point you are trying to make. Are you saying that capital gains _distributions_ by the fund are always reinvested into the fund and the shareholder gets no cash in hand; just more shares at a lower NAV, while distributions of the dividends collected by the fund over the year are always sent as cash and so the shareholder gets cash from which to pay the taxes due? And the notion of "you are not buying dividends - you are buying capital gains" seems to imply that the the distribution of the dividend income does not result in a reduction of the NAV, ...

Comment: @littleadv ... while distribution of the capital gains does result in a reduction of the NAV?

Comment: Not really, NAV has changed way before the reporting. You get the distributions on your 1099-DIV at the end of the year, but the actual transaction that resulted in the gain (and changed the NAV) might have happened months before you invested.

Comment: @littleadv But the capital gains that are distributed in December are _also_ (for the most part) capital gains that resulted from transactions that went on all year, and the NAV has been affected by these transactions as well. So, what is the difference? Why is buying the dividend OK but buying the capital gain bad? If I were foolish enough to insist on buying a mutual fund just before it declares a distribution, I would rather have the distribution be long-term capital gains (or qualified dividends) instead of ordinary dividends or short-term capital gains.

Comment: Because capital gains aren't really distributed. You get them reported on 1099-DIV, but you don't actually get the money (at least in some cases). This is treated as reduction of basis. These capital gains may be (and many times are) short term. So while your own investment is long term, you pay short term taxes on these capital gains and add it to your long term basis.

Comment: @littleadv You are right as usual. [The IRS states](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Reporting-Capital-Gains) "Capital gain distributions from mutual funds are reported to you on Form 1099-DIV, Dividends and Distributions. _Capital gain distributions are taxed as long-term capital gains regardless of how long you have owned the shares in the mutual funds._  If capital gain distributions are automatically reinvested, the reinvested amount is the basis of the additional shares purchased." but I am sure that your method is better and in accordance with IRC (instead of what the IRS _claims_ is the law).

Comment: I need to research that "long term ... regardless". I've seen S/T cap gains on my 1099-DIV in past years.

Comment: Necro but: Funds can and do distribute short-term capital gains, but such distributions are officially not 'capital gains distributions`; see [pub 550](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p550/ch01.html#en_US_2015_publink100010124). There also can be *undistributed* capital gains, which you don't receive but the *fund* pays the tax and you get *credit* for it; those are form 2439 not 1099, and described four paragraphs down from that link.